# when bootstrap.properties is there application.properties is ignoring in spring config client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using following spring-boot and spring-cloud version to develop spring cloud-config

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

And, using 2 property file `bootstrap.properties` and `application.properties`.

Spring is failing to read the property from `application.properties` file. Seems like it ignore the `application.properties` when `bootstrap.properties` exists inside the config-client.

Is the expected behavior of spring or I am missing anything in there.

Here is my source code : https://github.com/vskrahul/spring-cloud-config-client.git

Comment: What property? How do you recreate your issue?

Comment: My bad, `application.properties` was excluded in eclipse build path.